# Переход на другую страницу MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет друзья. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать

```
  <button class="login100-form-btn" id="btn">
      <!-- <a href="~/Home/Register" class="txt1">
          123
      </a>-->
      @Html.ActionLink("More information", "Register")
   </button>
```

На странице кнопка.
Хочу сделать клик по кнопке переход на станицу регистрации.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                var btn = $(this);
                btn.button('loading');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    url: '@Html.ActionLink("register", "Register")',
                    success: function (data) {
                        btn.button('reset');
                        $('.alert').css('display', 'block').text(data.title);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Почему то не работает. Как только не пробовал.

```
<!-- <a href="~/Home/Register" class="txt1">
              123
</a>-->
```

Так работает. Но тогда приходиться тыкать на ссылку а не на кнопку. Можно промахнуться спокойно. Вариант не очень

Comment: Сделайте ссылку ссылкой и стилизуйте при помощи css под кнопку. Если вы используете штатный фреймворк то в комплекте идёт бутстрап в котором буквально два готовых класса закинуть в стили.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста показать пример любой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам посоветовали в комментарии, стилизуйте ссылку под кнопку.

Например, так:

```
<a href="~/Home/Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</a>
```

или так:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Register","Home")" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</a>
```

[Buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/) - ссылка на документацию, где можно посмотреть и быстро выбрать нужный вид кнопки.

Comment: Так просто? надо же. Спасибо мужик.

Comment: ` <button class="login100-form-btn" id="myButton">
                                Registation
                        </button> $("#myButton").click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   document.location.href='@Url.Action("Register", "Home")';
    });` А правильно ли делать так через функцию?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев - если работает, то почему нет? Но сейчас такая тенденция - делать через css всё, что можно.

Comment: Вроде как в интернетах пишут что как то не очень так делать.